# What's the difference between the 'Move to' and 'Apply label' features in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I'm confused about the **Move to** and **Labels** feature in Gmail.

What's the difference between the two?
Why does the **Move to** option not appear sometimes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems as though there are 3 modes when viewing Gmail messages:

**1. Mailbox Mode:**

- Invoked by: clicking a mailbox on the top left (e.g. Inbox, Starred, etc.).
- Interface: Blue
- URL: ends with `#inbox`, `#starred`, etc.
- Top left button:

  - For Spam and Trash: **Delete forever**
  - For all the rest: **Archive**
- Buttons available: **Labels** and:

  - For Inbox, Spam and Trash: **Move to**
  - For all the rest: **Move to Inbox**
- Dragging a message will: **Move** it

**2. Label Mode:**

- Invoked by: clicking a label on the left.
- Interface: Green
- URL: ends with `#label/[my-label]`.
- Top left button: **Remove label "[my-label]"**.
- Buttons available: **Move to** and **Labels**.
- Dragging a message will: **Move** it

**3. Search Mode:**

- Invoked by: pressing the **Search Mail** button.
- Interface: Green
- URL: ends with `#search/[my-query]`.
- Top left button: **Archive** (There will also be the text **Search results for:[my-query]** to its left).
- Buttons available: **Move to Inbox** and **Labels**.
- Dragging a message will: **Label** it

Note that when you drag a message you can drop it on: Inbox, Starred, Spam, Trash, or one of your labels. If you are in search mode and drag a label onto a Mailbox, it will say **Label**, but it will actually **Move** the message.

You will notice that modes 1 and 2 behave almost exactly the same. When you click through to a message from a list, it will show the exact same buttons the list had.

Notice how **Move to** is only available when the concept of a folder is used. For example, the **Inbox** acts as a folder since a message can't be both in the **Inbox** and **Spam** (or **Trash**). Similarly, when you press on a label to go into Label Mode, it treats the label as if it were a folder (even though it may be tagged with multiple labels).

When you **Move** a message it **will remove the label/folder you are currently viewing from the message and apply a new one**. For example, say a message is marked as `label-a`, `label-b`, and `label-c`. Now you click on `label-b` on the left to enter Label Mode. Next, you move the message to `label-d`. What happens is `label-b` is removed and `label-d` is added. **The other labels remain on the message**. The message will now be labeled: `label-a`, `label-c`, `label-d`.

Similarly, if a message is in the **Inbox** and you **Move** it to the **Trash**, it will be removed from the **Inbox** and moved to the **Trash**.

When you use the **Label** feature, you simply choose which labels to add or remove. Nothing will be done automatically for you.

Answer (score 6):

Everthing in gmail is managed by labels, `Inbox` and `Trash` are also labels

`Move To XYZ` means remove `Inbox` label and apply label `XYZ` (if it was in Inbox)

While if you label it as `XYZ` then one more label `XYZ` will be added to that email resulting two labels `Inbox`,`XYZ` on your email

Comment: I think `Inbox` and `Trash` can better be described as folders since a message can't be in both the `Inbox` and `Trash`.

Comment: If it was as simple as `Move To XYZ` will remove `Inbox`, it would be much easier to understand. However, if the message is also tagged as `ABC`, and you view the `ABC` tag, when you press `Move To XYZ`, it will actually remain in the Inbox, and only the `ABC` tag will be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put:

- All mail state/attributes, including [Inbox], [Trash], etc, can be *considered* as Labels.
- However, **Mutual Exclusivity** must be maintained for these labels:
  [Inbox], [Sent Mail], [Drafts] and [Spam] [Trash]
  i.e. these labels cannot coexist; a mail may only have a maximum of one label out of these.

How to interpret:

1. Move to = Remove current label, Apply new label
2. +/- Label = Apply/Remove a label, ignore the rest.
3. Archive = Remove [Inbox] label
4. Delete = Apply [Trash] label. Because of Mutual Exclusivity of Labels, once [Trash] is applied, any [Inbox], [Sent Mail] etc labels will be removed.
5. Send a Draft email = Remove [Drafts] label, apply [Sent Mail] label.
6. All mail = Mails and drafts with **no** labels + Mails and drafts with (any combination of) labels

i.e. All mail excludes Trash, Spam, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In More Simple terms:  Label will simply add the Label but leave the message where it is. Move to will Add the label AND then archive the message.

Comment: It won't necessarily archive the message, though. The only time it will, is when you are in the `Inbox`.

Comment: To clarify, "archiving the message" just means "removing the Inbox label".

Comment: @Harlan: Try this: click on a label on the left hand side to see all of that label's messages. Now click on one of these messages. Next, choose to move this message to another label. You will notice that this did not archive the message (i.e. if the message was in the Inbox, it will remain in the Inbox). The only label/folder that was removed was the one you clicked on at the beginning of this procedure.